# Run javascript function on click dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, click, dropdown

How to run a javascript function in HTML page only when a dropdown menu is selected, before any option is selected in it. I run Query when dropdown menu is clicked on, with the following:

```
$("#_id").click(function () {
```

Then when I select something in the same dropdown menu, script runs again. When it's clicked on dropdown menu and when an option is selected. How to prevent from running again when I select something?

Comment: What is the usecase. We prefer dropdowns to only do stuff when we change them

Comment: Make sure the clicked element is what you expect?

Comment: I change data in other fields. Problem is, I don't want to change that field except when I click on it. Data in that dropdown is dependant on the other fields but they do not cause it to change.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have some undesired event bubbling. The click event on the menu option bubbles up to the menu, so both click handlers are executed. Check out the [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method. You should call that in your option click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the usecase? We prefer dropdowns to only do stuff when we change them

To answer:

Mousedown triggers before click

Click and hold the mouse to see the mousedown, release to see the click

```js
$("#_id").on("click",function() { console.log("clicked")});
$("#_id").on("mousedown",function() { console.log("mousedown")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="_id">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A usecase I have for this is refreshing the list of COM ports.